# Is there a way of deleting the tables inside a PDF using Python?

Tags: python, pdf

Is there a way of deleting the tables inside a PDF using Python? So far I've been working with *pdfplumber* to parse through the text within the PDF, and wanted to know is there is a way to ignore or delete the text inside a the tables.

Comment: Luis did you happen to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a Python package called Camelot. It is very efficient in extracting tabular data from PDF's. Here is the link to the [documentation](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: He needs a way to delete the tables though, not to extract them.